# How to suppress unnecessary output produced by fnmatch in Python?

Tags: python, fnmatch

I want to check is a file with a specific name exists or not in a directory. The directory contains 3 files:

```
20210401.NYSE.csv
20210402.NYSE.csv
20210403.NYSE.csv
```

The code that I'm using:

```
import sys, os, re, fnmatch

input_dir = '/scripts/test/'
date = sys.argv[1]
midfix = '.NYSE'
data_inpt_patt = date + midfix + '*' 

input_files = os.listdir(input_dir)
    for i in input_files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(i, data_inpt_patt):
            print(i + ' EXISTS')
        else:
            print(i + ' DOES NOT EXIST')
```

If I run the above code like this:

python check_files.py 20210401

I get this output:

```
20210401.NYSE.csv EXISTS
20210402.NYSE.csv DOES NOT EXIST
20210403.NYSE.csv DOES NOT EXIST
```

The desired output would be only the first line:

```
20210401.NYSE.csv EXISTS
```

How do I suppress the rest of the output (i.e. the filenames that do not match the pattern?)

Comment: suppress the else statement and you will get your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment, to get your complete desired output, I think you should use a function, for example:

```
def check_file_existence():
    for i in input_files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(i, data_inpt_patt):
            return data_inpt_patt + ' EXISTS'

    return data_inpt_patt + ' DOES NOT EXIST'



print(check_file_existence())
```

N.B: fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern) tests if first parameter 'filename' matches second parameter 'pattern'